# Fully customizing Laravel Nova interface

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm just getting started with Nova and am a novice with Vue.js.

I like Nova, but I want to reskin the dashboard and resources pages completely. There's just some functionality/features I need to customize that aren't there. Some examples:

- Responsive. Yes, I've seen a few git repos / packages that 'fix' this, but I want to rip out Tailwind completely and go with Bootstrap. That requires updating the html surrounds as well as the CSS.
- Remove the table view. For some resources, going to a card view instead of an old fashioned table view will work better to show the data. Again, this requires replacing the html. for the display.
- Icons. I want to change icons, use a different set and add my own for View/Edit/Delete.
- Update status on the Resource list view. Out of the box, I can add a status (on/off) for a resource, which appears in the table as green or red 'button'. I want to change the icons and also make it click to toggle from the list rather than having to go into the edit card to do this.

I'm still learning, so I might be making some incorrect assumptions, but it looks like the built-in resources components act the same way as a custom tool would do - meaning it's already packaged, compiled and deployed. In order to do some of the things I want to do, I'd need to modify the decompiled code for this 'tool', which doesn't appear to be available. I really don't want to rebuild the resources components from scratch (that's why I bought Nova), but I do want to customize it.

- Are my assumptions correct?
- Is there an decompiled version of the resources tool that can be duplicated and modified?
- Alternatively, is there a way to decompile the existing resource code so that I can duplicate and modify?
- (and finally) Am I thinking about this all wrong and is there a better way to do this?